# pandas calculate difference between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

Im new using stackoverflow

I want to calculate per id and month, the hours between (end and beg) two timestamp, what is the best way to get it please.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['x1', 'x1', 'x1', 'x2', 'x2', 'x2', 'x2']
       ,  'beg':['2021-01-01 00:00:00',
       '2021-02-03 00:00:00','2021-02-04 00:00:00','2021-02-05 00:00:00',
       '2021-02-06 00:00:00','2021-03-05 00:00:00','2021-04-01 00:00:00'],
          'end':['2021-01-02 00:00:00 ',
       '2021-02-03 12:00:00','2021-02-04 10:00:00','2021-02-05 10:00:00',
       '2021-02-06 10:00:00','2021-03-07 10:00:00','2021-05-08 00:00:00']}
```

**Expected output**

```
x1 01/2021  24
x1 02/2021  22
x2 02/2021    20
x2 03/2021     58
x2 04/2021 720
x2 05/2021 192
```

Comment: Can you explain the output at row `x1 01/2021  48`? Seems like this should be `24` instead of `48`.

Comment: it's my fault ! right 24. I updated it

Comment: how do you select the month, by beg date? end date? depending on which month is the date between beg and end?

Comment: Can you explain the last row : `x2 05/2021 744`?

Answer (score 3):

calculate the difference then groupby id and month. get the sum of the difference and calculate the hours

```
df.assign(diff=df[['beg', 'end']].diff(axis=1)['end']).groupby(['id', df['beg'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')]).agg('sum')/np.timedelta64(1, 'h')

             diff
id beg           
x1 01/2021   24.0
   02/2021   22.0
x2 02/2021   20.0
   03/2021   58.0
   04/2021  720.0
```

Comment: thank you @it_is_Chris I got this error **UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('<m8[ns]')**

Comment: @bifi, try converting your date columns to pandas `datetime` first (see my answer), then you can use this answer with no issue!

Answer (score 1):

First, we have to do some work-around to proper label each month:

```py
# Convert your data to datetime
df[['beg','end']] = df[['beg','end']].astype('datetime64[ns]')

# Identify rows with distinct months
months_diff = df.beg.dt.month < df.end.dt.month

# Function to split the months for posterior time comparison
def deal_with_diff_months(row):
    actual_month = [row['id'], row['beg'], row['end'].floor('d')]
    next_month = [row['id'], row['end'].floor('d'), row['end']]
    return actual_month, next_month

# Create a new dataframe for split months
df_tmp = df[months_diff].apply(deal_with_diff_months, axis=1)
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(df_tmp.explode().tolist(), columns=df.columns)

# Renew dataframe with split months
df = df[~months_diff].append(df_tmp)
```

Now we can use the code chunk below as originally answered:

```py
# Create a new column to group by month as well
df['month'] = df['beg'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')

# Group by id and month, then calculate and sum the difference
result = df.groupby(['id','month']).apply(lambda x: (x['end'] - x['beg']).sum())

# Convert the difference to hours
result = (result.dt.total_seconds()/60/60).astype(int)
```

---

Output:

```
id  month  
x1  01/2021     24
    02/2021     22
x2  02/2021     20
    03/2021     58
    04/2021    720
    05/2021      0
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right! It does end up like that because it subtracts one value from another (difference). In order to really aggregate them, we would need some aggregate method before calculating the difference (maybe summing the total seconds?).

Comment: I added the `sum` method in the answer. Although it's working as expected now, @It_is_Chirs answer is far better. Thx @Ben.T!

Comment: thank you . You helped me, then i can write this df to csv file ?

Comment: Use `result.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)`. See the documentation for this method [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: your solution seems don't cover this case x2 05/2021 192. Look at my original post please . Thank you

Comment: also to take a case with id:x1, beg: '2021-03-31 00:00:00' and end: 2021-04-01 10:00:00, i should have 24 for march and 10 for april. please tell me if im not clear !! thank youu

Comment: Yep, because I labeled the month based in the `beg` column. I figured out you wanted it, but I might be wrong. But, why do you cant to consider the `end column` as the label month? What is your goal with this analysis? We cannot label the months based in both `beg` and `end` columns, since they might differ. For me, it makes sense that "beg: '2021-03-31 00:00:00' and end: 2021-04-01 10:00:00" ends up with 34 hours. It depends on your goals...

Comment: I have to consider each month, i mean a client is connecting to our plateforme from 2021-03-31 00:00:00 to 2021-04-01 10:00:00, then i should be able to say that he was In 24H (march) and 10h (april). Hope that im clear now!

Comment: Hi @bifi, sorry the delay. Yeah, I got it now! I've updated the answer to split the months accordingly. There are probably better ways to achieve the same results, but here's an option meanwhile. Note that May doesn't have 192 h difference because it's 00:00:00 in your example, but I tested adding beg: '2021-03-31 00:00:00' and end: 2021-04-01 10:00:00 and it worked as expected. Please test it out! Best!

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for your response. For me it should be 168 as result because in may we count from 01/05/2021 to 08/05/2021 = 24*7. Do you see what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'id':['x1', 'x1', 'x1', 'x2', 'x2', 'x2', 'x2'], 
        'beg':['2021-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-02-03 00:00:00','2021-02-04 00:00:00','2021-02-05 00:00:00','2021-02-06 00:00:00','2021-03-05 00:00:00','2021-04-08 00:00:00'],
        'end':['2021-01-02 00:00:00','2021-02-03 12:00:00','2021-02-04 10:00:00','2021-02-05 10:00:00','2021-02-06 10:00:00','2021-03-07 10:00:00','2021-05-08 00:00:00']})

df['beg'] = pd.to_datetime(df['beg'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

hours_diff = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    diff = df['end'][i] - df['beg'][i]
    days, seconds = diff.days, diff.seconds
    hours = days * 24 + seconds // 3600
    hours_diff.append(hours)

df['hours_diff'] =  hours_diff

print(df)
```

Output:

```
id  beg                  end              hours_diff
0   x1   2021-01-01  2021-01-02 00:00:00     24
1   x1   2021-02-03  2021-02-03 12:00:00     12
2   x1   2021-02-04  2021-02-04 10:00:00     10
3   x2   2021-02-05  2021-02-05 10:00:00     10
4   x2   2021-02-06  2021-02-06 10:00:00     10
5   x2   2021-03-05  2021-03-07 10:00:00     58
6   x2   2021-04-08  2021-05-08 00:00:00     720
```

Comment: OP wants to aggregate per id and month, and using iterative method for calculating the time diff while vectorized solution are possible here is not really efficient :)